# What is 'closest best-ranked team' in ice hockey tournament tiebreaker?

Tags: ice-hockey, tie-breaker

I saw the term 'closest best ranked team' in the tie-braking rule of an ice hockey tournament.

https://www.iihf.com/en/events/2023/wmia/tournamentinfo/39354/tournament_info

If three or more teams are tied, the points, goal difference and goals scored are considered.
If they are still tied, the closest best ranked team is considered.

The original expression is

> Step 4: Should three or more teams still remain tied in points, goal
> difference and goals scored  then the results between each of the
> three teams and the closest best-ranked team outside the sub-group
> will be applied.  In this case the tied team with the best result (1.
> points, 2. goal difference, 3. more goals scored) against the closest
> best ranked-team will take precedence

Would there be an easy example to understand this rule?

For example, there are seven teams. The 1st, 2nd, 6th, 7th ranked teams are fixed and three teams are tied to determine the 3rd, 4th, and the 5th.

What is the 'closest best ranked team'? I think it may be the 2nd or 6th ranked team, but I am not sure.